# Question mark instead of hindi character, Google cloud function logs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a cloud function that working as middleware function for two internal data management systems.

The first system is posting data to cloud function then, data is handling on cloud function.

While logging posted data on cloud function from the first system, in logs Hindi characters are visible as a weird question mark signs.

While content-type of data is application/json.

Finally, the question is how to parse or access non-English or Hindi characters on Google Cloud function?

Answer (score 1):

Well the weird questions marks always indicate some character encoding problems.

Parsing non english characters works pretty much the same way, use the proper encoding.
In order to test i would use a middleware with StackDriver Logging , please refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging) , to find out more.